# Why isn't my Screensaver on/off event firing?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm having a problem with a custom event that picks up the screensaver on/off events, when the program starts and my screensaver turns on, my program isn't firing the screensaver on event!

My code is below, any and all help would be appreciated =]

```
class ScreensaverStatusWatcher
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, ref int ipvParam, int fuWinini);

        private const int screenSaverRunningStartup = -1;

        const int SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING = 114;

        private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        private bool ScreensaverStatus = false;

        private readonly System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        public int Interval { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ScreensaverOn;

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ScreensaverOff;

        public ScreensaverStatusWatcher()
        {
            timer.Interval = 1000 * 5;
            this.Initialize();
        }

        public ScreensaverStatusWatcher(int interval)
        {
            timer.Interval = interval;
            this.Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            timer.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }

        public bool IsScreenSaverRunning()
        {
            int screenSaverRunning = -1;
            int ok = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, ref screenSaverRunning, 0);

            //return - on fail
            if (ok == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return (screenSaverRunning != 0);
        }

        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.ScreensaverStatus && this.IsScreenSaverRunning())
            {
                this.ScreensaverStatus = true;
                this.OnScreensaverOn(new EventArgs());
            }
            else if(this.ScreensaverStatus && !this.IsScreenSaverRunning())
            {
                this.ScreensaverStatus = false;
                this.OnScreensaverOff(new EventArgs());
            }
        }

        private void OnScreensaverOn(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ScreensaverOn != null)
            {
                this.ScreensaverOn(this, e);
            }            
        }

        private void OnScreensaverOff(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ScreensaverOff != null)
            {
                this.ScreensaverOff(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
this is the code that uses this class

```
private ScreensaverStatusWatcher watcher = new ScreensaverStatusWatcher();

void watcher_ScreensaverOn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
            data.EventType = UserStateEvents.ScreensaverOn;

            PublishLogData(data);


        }

        void watcher_ScreensaverOff(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
            data.EventType = UserStateEvents.ScreensaverOff;

            PublishLogData(data);
```

Comment: Because I'm making a logging application which will push messages to a queue, which will then forward those messages to a database I.E I need to Log user activity, so I need to detect if the screensaver is on or off

Comment: The screensaver being on or off has little to do with user activity. A user could be using the machine remotely, the computer could be in a sleep mode, the screen saver could be disabled, etc. etc. What's wrong with the built-in Windows Auditing?

Comment: I'd like a useful answer to the current issue at hand if at all possible, I'm doing this as a project for work and this is the way I've been told to do it because it's going to be deployed internally as we've had issues with people not answering their phones, so if we know whose screensaver is on or off then we know who is at their desk and who isn't

Comment: also with the polling issue if you have a better solution in mind, please do share it =]

Comment: If all you care about is detecting user activity, my personal opinion is that you'd be better off installing a global input hook. If there is keyboard and/or mouse activity, assume a user is present. At least this doesn't require polling. It's also harder to defeat with hot corners...

Comment: Interesting solution, however sometimes people are discussing issues with colleagues etc so no keyboard/mouse activity could be erroneously interpreted as someone being not at their desk when they actually are, which is my reasoning for wanting to use the screensaver

Comment: also wouldn't using an input hook be more expensive than using polling? I'd be picking up every single mouse movement#

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some code you're not showing us, you don't invoke the Start method anywhere to set the timer running. Consequently, the Elapsed event never fires so you're never reading the  status of the screensaver.

Comment: Well, if you take *just* the code they've posted, then nothing creates an instance of this class either. Until we see the code that *uses* this class, it could be anything.